# Cannot figure out how to save this field into database for Android room

Tags: android, android-room, typeconverter

I am developing database with `Android Room`,and I want to store `JSON` data like the following into database.

```
@Entity(tableName = "bank_info")
data class BankInfo(

    @PrimaryKey
    @SerializedName("id")
    @ColumnInfo(name = "id") val id: Long,

    @SerializedName("name")
    @ColumnInfo(name = "name") val name: String,

    @TypeConverters(BankTypeConverter::class)
    @SerializedName("banks")
    @ColumnInfo(name = "banks") val banks: List<Bank>,

){
    data class Bank (
        @SerializedName("bankid")
        @ColumnInfo(name = "id") val id: Long,

        @SerializedName("name")
        @ColumnInfo(name = "name") val name: String

    )
}
```

And it show the error:

```
error: Cannot figure out how to save this field into database. You can consider adding a type converter for it.
    private final java.util.List<com.bank.wallet.BankInfo.Bank> banks = null;
                                                                                                      ^
```

I have search for above error, and use the the `@TypeCovert` like the following:

```
class BankTypeConverter {

    @TypeConverter
    open fun lisiToString(list: List<Bank>): String {
        if (list == null || list.size === 0) {
            return ""
        }
        val gson = Gson()
        val type = object : TypeToken<List<Bank>>() {

        }.type
        val json = gson.toJson(list, type)

        return json
    }

    @TypeConverter
    open fun StringToArray(value: String): List<Bank> {

        val gson = Gson()
        val type = object : TypeToken<List<Bank>>() {

        }.type
        return gson.fromJson(value, type)

    }

}
```

But it does not working , did I missing something ?

How to write the `@TypeCovert` for above format ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a code snippet

```
class Converter {

    @TypeConverter
    public static List<Bank> restoreBankList(String listOfString) {
        return new Gson().fromJson(listOfString, new TypeToken<List<Bank>>() {}.getType());
    }

    @TypeConverter
    public static String saveListAsString(List<Bank> listOfString) {
        return new Gson().toJson(listOfString);
    }

}
```

now you should tell the `RoomDatabase` that you are using `@TypeConverter`

```
@Database(entities = YourClass, version = 1)
@TypeConverters({Converter.class})
public abstract class RadarDatabaseHolder extends RoomDatabase {



// here is your usual code

}
```

Types will be converted automatically while doing DB operations